# Change Unity 3d viewport shortcuts to match Blender?

Tags: unity, 3d, blender, viewport

The shortcuts in Unity are more similar to Maya (**Alt+Middle** for 3d orientation, **LeftClick** select, etc). I've looked into **Edit -> Shortcuts** but couldnt find them. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're not the only person that wanted to make Unity more like Blender, and on the Unity forum someone has tried to script the editor to make it behave a bit more like Blender by adjusting the keyboard shortcuts. See https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-editor-viewport-navigation-hotkeys.81673/

There's also the [official documentation for adding your own menu items with keyboard shortcuts](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html).

I'm not sure if there's a way to modify the mouse controls though. The [scene navigation documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SceneViewNavigation.html) doesn't mention any control customization options.